# Is it possible light is absorbed and re-emitted in empty space

Tags: speed-of-light, quantum-electrodynamics, vacuum

Considering empty space is not empty, particles are continuously created and destroyed. Theoretically can a photon off incoming light be destroyed then be re-emitted? If so, when it is regenerated would it not be with a speed relative to the frame of the local empty space?

Could that then explain why light is always measured at speed c?

Comment: the answers to [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/172999/propagation-speed-of-photons-when-taking-higher-order-qft-corrections-into-accou) might be interesting

Answer (score 0):

Those are virtual photons that are being created and destroyed in vacuum, not real ones with speed c.